# Как скопировать поля и вставить текущую дату в SQL запросе INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, delphi

Есть две почти одинаковые таблицы и отличается вторая от первой лишь наличием столбца ДАТА. Нужно скопировать все столбцы из первой таблицы во вторую и в поле ДАТА вставить системное время. Пишу так:

```
DataModule3.ADOQuery2.Active:=False;
 DataModule3.ADOQuery2.SQL.Clear;
 DataModule3.ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Операции(Наименование, Производитель, Модель, Количество, Цена, Дата)');
 DataModule3.ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT Наименование, Производитель, Модель, Количество, Цена, "Now", FROM Корзина');
 DataModule3.ADOQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

Ругается и говорит, что ошибка синтаксиса `INSERT INTO`. Пробовал даже через переменную, и всё та же история.

Comment: 1. Now поддерживается СУБД? Сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

А если так?

```
' SELECT Наименование, Производитель, Модель, Количество, Цена, Now() FROM Корзина'
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понял твой вопрос:

у тебя есть таблица А со столбцами а1, а2, а3 и таблица B со столбцами а1, а2, а3, a4. Ты пишешь, что

> нужно скопировать все столбцы из
> первой таблицы во вторую

Зачем, если во второй таблице уже есть столбцы первой таблицы?

Если тебе требуется скопировать все значения из первой таблицы во вторую добавив в последнее поле дата, то я бы поступил следующим образом:

```
DataModule3.ADOQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Операции(Наименование, Производитель, Модель, Количество, Цена, Дата) SELECT Наименование, Производитель, Модель, Количество, Цена, '+DateToStr(Today)+', FROM Корзина');
```